# Statistics/Data Science: Real world example for a donut destribution?

Tags: statistics, data-science

I'm looking for different real world examples for donut derivations (in the statistic meaning).

[donut derivation plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrGq4.jpg)

For the most other derivations, I found good examples.
But for this the only one is the way to focus a laser beam:

https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Donut-shaped-laser-beam-for-thermocapillary-induced-dewetting-a-Microscopic-pictures_fig2_274400395

But this wouldn´t fit to e.g. a classication problem.

Has anybody a good source oder idea, where donut derivations are existing in real world data?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Interesting question, but it's off topic for SO. Try stats.stackexchange.com instead, or maybe datascience.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks a lot, didn´t know them! All machine learning questions ends in SO ;-).